# rubyで小数の掛け算。桁指定。

Tags: ruby

1.2345678901234567890123456789012 * 9.8765432109876543210987654321098

32桁同士の小数を掛け算したときに、32桁で答えを表示するにはどうしたら良いですか？

Comment: 小数点を書き忘れていたので、編集しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
n = BigDecimal.new("1.2345678901234567890123456789012",32)
n2 = BigDecimal.new("9.8765432109876543210987654321098",32)
n.mult(n2,32).to_s #=> "12.193263113702179522618503273386"
```

でいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。multで桁数指定ですね